# Execute python code in atom editor for windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, atom-editor

I just started using atom editor in my windows 10 for coding in python 2 but I'm unable to execute the python code in the editor.I tried installing packages such as script,atom-runner and it shows this error in atom-runner package:

[image: atom-runner]

and this in script package:

[image: script]

I searched in the net but couldn't get any satisfying answers.Please someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Atom Runner error message, it looks like your code includes an `input()` statement. Atom Runner and the `script` package are essentially just spawning new processes in the background to run your code. However, `input()` expects an input that it can't get (because it's running in the background). Atom Runner recognizes this and throws the error, and `script` appears to hang because it's waiting on user input.

The solution for this particular situation is to use a terminal (either one already on your machine or using [one of many Atom terminal packages](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=terminal)).